# Swift Combine: is it available to obeserve zip multiple UIbuttons status?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I would like to enable "Proceed" button when every checkbox buttons are selected using combine and publisher.

There must be the way to zip those multiple UIButtons(works on UIKit) isSelected status are all true.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the relevant code that accompanies this?

Comment: There's no specific yet. Only check buttons are linked with IBOutlet on UIView. I wonder if I must add @Published boolean property which can be observable object and change value when checkbox button status is being changed instead create and extension UIControl and add custom publisher...

Comment: do you create these views using SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: @Yodagama It's UIKit.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/721/

Answer (score 1):

I would solve the problem using `combineLatest` instead of `zip`:

```
import Cocoa
import Combine

let description1 = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
let description2 = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
let description3 = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)

let proceedEnable = description1.combineLatest(description2, description3)
    .map { (triplet: (Bool, Bool, Bool)) in triplet.0 && triplet.1 && triplet.2 }


let subscription = proceedEnable.sink { print($0) }

description1.send(true)
description2.send(true)
description3.send(true)

description3.send(false)
```

You can copy and paste this code into a playground.
The `CurrentValueSubject` represents the state of the checkboxes.
The `proceedEnable` is a stream for the enabled state of the "Proceed" button.  It will emit a value any time any of the description streams change and will only emit true if the three `descriptionX` values are all true.